# How to interact in a mixed-gender Islamic school?

Tags: men-women, school, behavior

I recently relocated to Malaysia and entered an Islamic school. However, classes are mixed. I do not talk to the girls unnecessarily, but the problem is that they start talking unnecessarily to me. What should I do?

Should I ignore them, or tell them not to talk to me? I just reply as briefly as possible and try to end the conversation as quickly as possible.

Comment: you should try to move to school, which does not have co-education, otherwise, try your Best to stay away from them as possible

Comment: The idea is that there is no proper school that doesn't have co-education :/

Comment: so openly tell them not to talk to you. and have least possible communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I recommend is to talk with them regarding school work at the classroom when others are around and nothing else about personal life.  Lower your gaze as much as possible and keep your distance.  Never be alone with any of the girls because it will eventually lead to Zina.  If you have difficulty, try fasting or get married if you are legally able to do so.

Here is a website to help you out brother http://islamhouse.com/en/fatwa/189684/ and it is entitled "Dealing with temptations of women."